# error when trying to update mongodb using a flask variable for the fieldname

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, flask, mongodb-query, flask-mongoengine

I am working with flask trying to update a mongodb collection which works fine when I state the fieldname that needs updated, but I want to fieldname to be a variable depending on which needs updated.  This works fine to update the field:

```
Scoresenglish6.objects(user_id=user_id).update(E6001=str(score))
```

But, the fieldname being updated can change (so in this case it is "E6001") so I have the fieldname needing updated as a variable called field_name:

```
score = "10"
field_name = "E6001"
Scoresenglish6.objects(user_id=user_id).update(field_name=str(score))
```

Then I get the error:

> mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "field_name"

obviously because there is no field name called field_name.  Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance, I'm a home coder working on a home project so apologies if this seems vague and not well explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) to achieve what you want.

Try this:

```
score = "10"
field_name = "E6001"
Scoresenglish6.objects(user_id=user_id).update(locals()['field_name']=str(score))
```

Have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/locals) to understand how `locals()` work and how to use them.